# Reconvert to list of float values from python string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a field for geo-co-ordinates in my pandas dataframe.
For some reason it is treating it as a string.

> `geoward.loc[1, 'coordinates']`

output

```
'[[73.77359300000002,18.547145],[73.773696,18.546857],[73.77373,18.546758000000004],[73.77389,18.546786],[73.773971,18.546785999999997],[73.774031,18.546775999999998],[73.774092,18.546752],[73.7742,18.546692],[73.774329,18.546611],[73.77442,18.54656],[73.774505,18.546529],[73.774841,18.546381],[73.774863,18.546373000000003],[73.775058,18.546299],[73.775229,18.546243999999998],[73.775425,18.546182],[73.775694,18.546111]]'
```

Here I want it as a list, so that I can access each element from it. i.e `coordinates[0] =[[73.77359300000002,18.547145]` and further each float value from it.

How can I convert the string so that I can access it.

Comment: You have used enclosed your list with '. Please remove '  from the declaration.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Sorry my question was ambiguous. I edited it now. The coordinates are stored in a dataframe , and the type is string.

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: Fix the dataframe on creation or read about `ast.literal_eval` to get the list from the string: [using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Answer (score -1):

Only use eval function.

```
coordinates = '[[73.77359300000002,18.547145],[73.773696,18.546857],[73.77373,18.546758000000004],[73.77389,18.546786],[73.773971,18.546785999999997],[73.774031,18.546775999999998],[73.774092,18.546752],[73.7742,18.546692],[73.774329,18.546611],[73.77442,18.54656],[73.774505,18.546529],[73.774841,18.546381],[73.774863,18.546373000000003],[73.775058,18.546299],[73.775229,18.546243999999998],[73.775425,18.546182],[73.775694,18.546111]]'

coordinates = eval(coordinates)

print(coordinates[0])
print('lat', coordinates[0][0])
print('long', coordinates[0][1])
```